# UPDATE and INSERT don't work in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I use this code to retreive an id. It works:

```
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","proyectoacademias" )

        cursor = db.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT id FROM test WHERE url=\'"
        sql = sql + self.start_urls[0]
        sql = sql + "\'"

        cursor.execute(sql)

        data = cursor.fetchone()

        for row in data:
            self.id_paper_web=str(row)

        db.close()
```

It gives me the id of the current row I have to update...

But then I try to update or to insert, it doesn't work....

```
    def guardarDatos(self):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","proyectoacademias" )

    cursor = db.cursor()

    sql = "UPDATE test SET abstract=\'"+str(self.abstracto)+"\', fecha_consulta=\'"+str(self.fecha_consulta)+"\', anio_publicacion=\'"+str(self.anio_publicacion)+"\', probabilidad="+str(self.probabilidad)+" WHERE id = "+str(self.id_paper_web)

    print "\n\n\n"+sql+"\n\n\n"
    cursor.execute(sql)      

    for i in range (len(self.nombres)):
        sql = "INSERT INTO test_autores VALUES (\'"+self.nombres.keys()[i]+"\', "+str(self.id_paper_web)+", \'"+self.instituciones[self.nombres[self.nombres.keys()[i]]]+"\', "+str((i+1))+")"
        print "\n\n\n"+sql+"\n\n\n"
        cursor.execute(sql)

    db.close()
```

I print every sql query I sent and they seem to be fine... no exceptions thrown, just no updates or inserts in the database...

Comment: `db.commit()`? ... 15 characters. - Also, parameterized queries.  Please don't construct them as strings.  SQL Injection is a real concern.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have write access to the database.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're using [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/python) correctly, if at all, which could lead to very severe SQL injection problems with this code.

Comment: @tadman - Oh man, little Bobby Tables.  I chuckle every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must commit ... or set the db to auto commit

```
db.commit()
```

lots of py sqlite3 tutorials out there

> By default, the sqlite3 module opens transactions implicitly before a
>   Data Modification Language (DML) statement (i.e.
>   INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/REPLACE), and commits transactions implicitly
>   before a non-DML, non-query statement (i. e. anything other than
>   SELECT or the aforementioned).
>
> So if you are within a transaction and issue a command like CREATE
>   TABLE ..., VACUUM, PRAGMA, the sqlite3 module will commit implicitly
>   before executing that command. There are two reasons for doing that.
>   The first is that some of these commands don’t work within
>   transactions. The other reason is that sqlite3 needs to keep track of
>   the transaction state (if a transaction is active or not).
>
> You can control which kind of BEGIN statements sqlite3 implicitly
>   executes (or none at all) via the isolation_level parameter to the
>   connect() call, or via the isolation_level property of connections.
>
> If you want autocommit mode, then set isolation_level to None.
>
> Otherwise leave it at its default, which will result in a plain
>   “BEGIN” statement, or set it to one of SQLite’s supported isolation
>   levels: “DEFERRED”, “IMMEDIATE” or “EXCLUSIVE”.

- http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html  Section 11.13.6

Comment: The question seems to pertain to MySQL but this may be relevant.

Comment: In addition, you should use a try-except-final structure, so if something fails, the final can always rollback.